# How to loop through in a PHP web application?

Tags: php, html

Creating a number guessing game in PHP for class and I've hit a snag.  I've got it so I can make multiple guesses, but I want to limit it to a specific number of guesses, set by the user.  I'm trying to figure out how to add in a while or a do while loop.

Here's my basic setup.  I have two .php pages (index.php and phpGame.php).
On the index page I have 3 text boxes so the player can enter in 3 numbers.
The first 2 are for the bottom and the top of the range of numbers to guess (so they could do between 1 and 10, or 1 and 100, or 5 and 67, whatever they want).
The 3rd text box they can enter in the number of tries they want to guess the number in (1, 3, 54, 101, whatever).

When they click the "Begin Game button" it passes those numbers to the phpGame.php page.  Which then generates a random number within the range the entered.

There is a text box on this page where they can enter in a number and click "Submit Answer" and it'll let them know if they are too high, or too low, or if they got it correct.  However, they can guess as many times as they want and I'd like it to simply loop for however many tries they specified and then end the game and say they didn't get it in the specified number of tries.  Everything worked fine until I put in the do/while loop and now the phpGame.php page won't even load now.

Here's my code:
index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['setMin'] = $minNumber;
$_SESSION['setMax'] = $maxNumber;
$_SESSION['setTries'] = $numTries;

?>

<form method="GET" action="phpGame.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Please choose the bottom of the range of number to guess 
from:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="setMin" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Please choose the top of the range of numbers to guess from:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="setMax" value="10">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                How many tries would you like to guess my number?:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="setTries" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <input value="Begin Game" name="begin" type="submit">
</form>
```

phpGame.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$minNumber = $_GET['setMin'];
$maxNumber = $_GET['setMax'];
$numTries = $_GET['setTries'];
$randomNum = rand($minNumber,$maxNumber);

do {
    if (!isset($_POST["guess"])) {
        $_SESSION["count"] = 0; //Initialize count
        $message = "Welcome to the guessing machine!";
        $_POST["numtobeguessed"] = $randomNum;
        #echo $_POST["numtobeguessed"];
    } else if ($_POST["guess"] > $_POST["numtobeguessed"]) { //greater than
            $message = $_POST["guess"]." is too big! Try a smaller number.";
            $_SESSION["count"]++; //Declare the variable $count to increment by 1.
        } else if ($_POST["guess"] < $_POST["numtobeguessed"]) { //less than
                $message = $_POST["guess"]." is too small! Try a larger number.";
                $_SESSION["count"]++; //Declare the variable $count to increment by 1.
            } else { // must be equivalent
                    $_SESSION["count"]++;
                    $message = "Well done! You guessed the right number in ".$_SESSION["count"]." attempt(s)!";
                    unset($_SESSION["count"]);//Include the $count variable to the $message to show the user how many tries to took him.
                }
    } while ($count < $numTries);

echo "I'm sorry you didn't guess the right number in ".$numTries.". The number I was thinking of was ".$randomNum.".";
?>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>A PHP number guessing script</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
    <h3><?php echo $minNumber, $maxNumber, $numTries, $_SESSION["numtobeguessed"], $_SESSION["count"]; ?></h3>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <p><strong>Type your guess here:</strong>
            <input type="text" name="guess"></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="numtobeguessed" 
                   value="<?php echo $_POST["numtobeguessed"]; ?>" ></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit your guess"/></p>
    <p><a href="index.php">Start a New Game</a></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your while statement uses $count.  But $count is not set anywhere, you always user $_SESSION["count"].  You could use the for statement for that loop (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Answer (score 1):

You should rebegin to learn Basics.

1 -

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['setMin'] = $minNumber;
$_SESSION['setMax'] = $maxNumber;
$_SESSION['setTries'] = $numTries;

?>
```

This makes no sense. These variables are not initialized. So ur writing 0 to your Session

2 - You should not write to $_POST.

```
$_POST["numtobeguessed"] = $randomNum;
```

This usage of POST makes also no sense. Normally u use it only for reading from $_POST.

3 - When im right $_SESSION is always writing to the Filesystem. So in best practice u use normal $foo variables and Save them at the end of the Script to $_SESSION

4 - What u should do in phpGame.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//Check if your sending a new Game request
if(isset($_GET['setMin'] ... {
//..your variables
//generate Random number, save it to session
$_SESSION['randNumber'] = rand($minNumber,$maxNumber);
//initialize the used and available tries
$_SESSION['usedTries'] = 0;
$_SESSION['numTries'] = $numTries;
}

//then you have always only on $_POST request/response
//to make a loop outer POST check makes no sense
if (isset($_POST["guess"])) {

//with one request we can make one try..so we need no loop
if($_SESSION['usedTries'] <= $_SESSION['numTries']) {

//do your stuff
//like $_POST["guess"] == $_SESSION['randNumber']

//iterate the used Tries
$_SESSION['usedTries']++;

}

}

?>
```

I hope I was a help^^

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$count` is neither defined nor being incremented. You need to do something like `$count = 0;` before the loop and increment it `$count++;` in the loop as each guess is made.

Comment: If i take the do/while loop out, it does count and increment.  When you finally guess the number it does say, Congrats you guess the number in X tries, so it's counting.  I've tried both using the $count and $_SESSION["count"] in the While condition and still the same issue, with the loop in there the 2nd page just doesn't come up and allow the user to start guessing.